# Почему русский текст из api-запроса не отображается, хотя при выводе русских букв с помощью System.out.println всё работает?

Tags: java, консоль, кодировка, intellij-idea

По какой-то причине не отображаются названия тестов на кириллице в консоли, так же при получении ответа от api-запроса прилетают кракозябры:

[image: Скриншот проблемы]

При этом весь остальной русский текст в консоли, будь то `System.out.println` или логирование, отображается верно.

Что я пробовал делать:

1. Добавлял строки `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8` и `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` в файл `idea64.exe.vmoptions` .
2. Добавлял строки `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8` и `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` в IntelijIdea по пути `File->Settings->Editor->File encodings`
3. вводил `chcp` в консоль (пишет 866).
4. В настройках самой IntelijIdea пробовал ставить разные кодировки (UTF-8, windows-1251)

Comment: @Зонтик, не нужно все заворачивать в метки.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, тут дело не в Intellij Idea, а в API, который возвращает ответ, ведь даже ошибка звучит как:

> excepted: <Операция выполнена успешно.> but was: <*текст со сбитой кодировкой*>

Проверьте данный запрос через другие среды. Например, Postman

Если действительно проблема в API, попробуйте добавить в заголовок "Content-Type" конкретную кодировку. utf-8 или windows-1251. Выглядеть это будет примерно так:
`Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

У меня была аналогичная проблема. В моем случае оказалось, что версия java и текущая версия IDE плохо совместимы. Помог переход на java 17.